# users.length and users undefined error testing async code using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have this simple component that fetch data and render a list

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Loader = styled.div``;

const Row = styled.li`
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
`;

export const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5";

function Users() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUsers() {
      try {
        const {
          data: { results }
        } = await axios.get(url);
        setUsers(results);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {users && users.length === 0 ? (
        <Loader>Loading...</Loader>
      ) : (
        users &&
        users.map(user => <Row data-testid="row">{user.name.first}</Row>)
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Users;
```

if you notice I have to do double checking on the users state to make the test pass.

If I don't do double check for example instead of doing users && users.length I do users.length I got this error in my test

[image]

My test is to check the loader is render properly before the users list came.

```
test("loader component when it's fetching data", () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Users />);
  expect(getByText(/loading.../i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I think I shouldn't change the implementation code for the sake of test case right? I still wonder why users is not empty array by default when I run the test? Why do I need to double check the users object?

Comment: Are you mocking axios by any chance?

Comment: @Gpx this test worked https://pastebin.com/raw/u8DeJWg0

I have changed the axios.js in ```__mock__``` folder to 

```export default {
  get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: {} })
};
```

Comment: Try to log `users` before and after the fetch runs. My guess is that your mock returns an empty value

Comment: your test for loading is successful.But still your component is trying to make a api call and it fails and your users will be undefined and js throw's an error.To overcome this just spy on your axios get method and tell it to return a list of users.